# OpenAL playing audio from certain timestamp

Tags: c++, audio, game-engine, openal

I am writing a dialogue system for my game engine in C++. In order to group dialogue together I am having different dialogue sections placed within one file, and one buffer. Therefore how do I tell OpenAL to play the buffer from a specific time (or sample it doesn't really matter to me) into the buffer. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void PlayFromSpecifiedTime(ALfloat seconds) const
{
    alSourcef(source, AL_SEC_OFFSET, seconds);
    alSourcePlay(source);
}
```

Or, if you want to play from a certain sample from the buffer:

```
void PlayFromSpecifiedSample(ALint sample) const
{
    alSourcei(source, AL_SAMPLE_OFFSET, sample);
    alSourcePlay(source);
}
```

You can also add a check at the beginning to see if you're not trying to skip to a certain time (or sample) beyond the total amount from the buffer. If it does, you simply `return;` out of it. This assumes you know what you're doing.